# Python class Import just prints Source Code (Any suggestions?)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to import a class

```
# import folder.folder.classfile
```

But weirdly whatever code follows, Python3.6 just prints out some source code. I do not know from where the code 
I have no clue where I should start debugging as the code comes from a large repository.

A small part of the output directs to the Wikipedia site of the Floyd–Warshall algorithm. So it might be a third party software causing the trouble. But why is it simply printing the stuff? The problem started after installing these libraries:

```
['setuptools_scm', 'pandas>=0.23.3', 'happybase', 'jaydebeapi', 'pandasql', 'pycurl', 'networkx',
                      'visJS2jupyter', 'matplotlib', 'py2cytoscape', 'joblib', 'dill', 'pyaml', 'colorlog',
                      'ipywidgets>=7.0.5', 'prometheus-client', 'cython', 'psutil', 'ipyleaflet', 'testfixtures',
                      'python-crontab', 'jpype1','sympy','yattag', 'docker', 'coverage']
```

I am just looking for suggestions on where to look. I also redid the install.

EDIT: I did a workaround. Something in the IJupyter caused the problem. I just commented the line out, as I don`t really need to use it.

Comment: "prints out some source code" is not specific enough. Do you get an error message? Python doesn't just output source code unless you `open` a Python script and print its contents

Comment: That is a lot of libraries, can you narrow it down more?

Comment: Unfortunately there are no error messages. Maybe on top but the code spams the command line. I also cant echo the output to another file for some reason. Not via the command line with ">" nor inside the python program.

I cannot narrow it down, as the libraries are needed to execute the repository. Maybe I´ll just delete all python3.6 libs and try a re-install.